# How to identify if a value is between to values in a array and repeat for the entire array - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a long list of numbers (sizes actually) in column F. In column N and O, I have a lower and upper bound respectively. In column M, I have a label for each set of bounds (A, B, C, D, E, etc.)

What I need to do do is check each value in F. If the value is between the first items in N and O, A will be put in column E next to the value being checked. If not I want to go down the list of N and O until I identify which bounds the value is between and select the corresponding letter.

I'll drag this code down to do the same check for every value in column F.

For example I have typed =IF(AND(F7<$O$13,F7>$N$13),$M$13, "") into E9 and outputs "F". However it only checks the bounds corresponding to letter F. If this IF statement were to result in False, I would need the formula to then check O/N/M14, then O/N/M15, etc.

Happy to clarify if the question is confusing and appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort M:P on N Ascending and use:

```
=INDEX(M:M,MATCH(F7,N:N))
```

[image]

---

If you cannot sort the lookup table then use:

```
=INDEX(M:M,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($N$8:$N$19)/((F7>=$N$8:$N$19)*(F7<=$O$8:$O$19)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: THank you for the answer, this worked great. Took me a while to understand exactly how the function works, but I now understand 90% of it, and was apply to apply it for this situation.